# Error en controllers en ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, postman

estoy implementando Jwt en mi webApi y me genera error al llamar a la ruta , en mi controlador esta el código que genera el token y también los otros servicios con el Authorize en cada uno hasta que me genere el token que me permita utilizar los servicios , ¿ cual seria mi error que estoy cometiendo? por que me genera ese error en el postman. Tambien no sé si crear otro controlador y ahí poner el código del token y los otros servicios en otro controlador con el Authorize ¿no habrá problema?

**este es el error que me da en el postman**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple constructors accepting all given argument types have been found in type 'AjiPu.Controllers.ClienteController'. There should only be one applicable constructor.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.TryFindMatchingConstructor(Type instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes, ConstructorInfo& matchingConstructor, Nullable`1[]& parameterMap)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.FindApplicableConstructor(Type instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes, ConstructorInfo& matchingConstructor, Nullable`1[]& matchingParameterMap)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(Type instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.CreateActivator(ControllerActionDescriptor descriptor)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.CreateControllerFactory(ControllerActionDescriptor descriptor)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvokerCache.GetCachedResult(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvokerProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionInvokerProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionInvokerFactory.CreateInvoker(ActionContext actionContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointFactory.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateRequestDelegate>b__0(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 51
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:44397
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
Postman-Token: fd759aab-b1d9-46ea-b627-50908eb97c40
```

**este es mi controller**

```
using AjiPu.Data;
using AjiPu.Models;
using JWTAuthDemo.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace AjiPu.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ClienteController : ControllerBase
    {
        //context de la base de datos
        private readonly SVMQASContext _context;
        public ClienteController(SVMQASContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        private IConfiguration _config;

        //llamamos al configuration
        public ClienteController(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        //Login que genera el token 
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody] UserModel login)
        {
            IActionResult response = Unauthorized();

            var user = AuthenticateUser(login);

            if (user != null)
            {
                var tokenStr = GenerateJSONWebToken(user);
                response = Ok(new { token = tokenStr });
            }

            return response;
        }

        private UserModel AuthenticateUser(UserModel login)
        {
            UserModel user = null;
            if (login.UserName == "123" && login.Password == "123")
            {
                user = new UserModel { UserName = "AshprogHelp", EmailAddres = "ashproghelp@gmail.com", Password = "123" };

            }
            return user;

        }

        private string GenerateJSONWebToken(UserModel userinfo)
        {
            var securutyKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securutyKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub,userinfo.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email,userinfo.EmailAddres),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti,Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            };

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(

                issuer: _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                audience: _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
                signingCredentials: credentials);

            var encodetoken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            return encodetoken;
        }

        // GET: api/<ClienteController>
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("listaCliente")]
        public ActionResult Get()
        {
            var data = from clientes in _context.UgvmaPerfilClientes select clientes;
            return Ok(data);
            //return Ok(_context.UgvmaPerfilClientes.ToList());
        }

        // GET api/<ClienteController>/5
        //[Route("buscarCliente")]

        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet("buscar/{id}")]
        public ActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            var data = from cliente in _context.UgvmaPerfilClientes
                       where cliente.Id.Equals(id)
                       select cliente;
            return Ok(data);
        }

        // PUT api/<ClienteController>/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<ClienteController>/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Incluye el `startup.cs` por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en la inyección de dependencias, como en la clase hay dos constructores y ambos esperan una dependencia el inyector no puede hacer su trabajo ya que solo puede llamar un constructor para crear el objeto y eso produce el error.

Eso se soluciona recibiendo ambas dependencias en un mismo constructor:

```
 public ClienteController(SVMQASContext context, IConfiguration config)
    {
          _context = context;
          _config = config;
    }
```

Comment: el Jwt se puede poner en este controlador y puedo autorizar en otros controladores? o también se tiene que poner el código del Token

Comment: No me queda clara tu duda.

Comment: se puede poner [Authorize] en otros controladores y utilizarlo? o también se tendría que poner el jwt para cada controlador

Comment: Sí, con poner [Authorize]  en los demás controladores debe funcionar. [Authorize] no tiene nada que ver con la generación del token.